# My code runs fine as standalone app but takes forever in JSP. Why?

Tags: java, jsp, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I need to call an external .jar file on the server from my jsp page. I first tried running a simple java program to call the jar file. It worked within a second. My code was:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class callJar_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String jarPath = "C:\\Oyster3.4\\Oyster_v.3.4.13.jar";
        String scriptPath = "C:\\Oyster3.4\\IdentityResolutionRunScript.xml";
        String args1[] = {"java", "-jar", jarPath, "-r", scriptPath};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args1);
        Process p = pb.start();
    }
}
```

Then i tried to implement the same in JSP. My code was:

```
<%
    String s = null;
    String jarPath = "C:\\Oyster3.4\\Oyster_v.3.4.13.jar";
    String scriptPath = "C:\\Oyster3.4\\IdentityResolutionRunScript.xml";
    String args[] = {"java", "-jar", jarPath, "-r", scriptPath};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);

    final Process p = pb.start();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    } 

%>
```

The run never completes, takes hours. Please help! How can i speed it up? 
I used `runTime.exec()` too but that is extremely slow.

Comment: why don't you integrate the jar in your project and call the class directly ?

Comment: I have copied the jar to my web-inf/lib folder, but i'll be grateful if you could tell me how to call the class directly? This is the first time i'm working with java, totally relying on the internet.

Comment: if you're calling with -jar, then this jar must have a manifest file inside declaring the "executable" class

Comment: Yes, open it with 7zip or so and look in WEB-INF/MANIFEST.MF, "Main-Class: x.y.Z" and call `x.y.Z.main(new String[]);`

Comment: I think s = stdInput.readLine() is what is taking all that time.. I cannot see that in your main program. Have you tested it?

Comment: I found the Manifest.mf file. Thank you. But when i use cmd to call the jar directly from the prompt, i write: java -jar C:\\Oyster3.4\\Oyster_v.3.4.13.jar -r C:\\Oyster3.4\\IdentityResolutionRunScript.xml. So how do i call the main class with these parameters?

Comment: The same problem exists even when i remove s = stdInput.readLine().

Comment: @UtsavChatterjee the xml path is the second string in the class main(String[] args) argument. the first is the "-r"